# Storage check and glance options missing after factory reset of Lumia 720

Tags: glance, reset, storage-check

I reset my Lumia 720 (with the Black update), but after the reset the Storage check and Glance options are missing from settings. How do I get them back?

Comment: What OS version does the Phone's about page show?

Comment: Have you tried SysAppPusher? (Available on the WP store)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because after a factory reset you need to manualy update the system apps that have been updated since the time your factory OS version was launched. Since you are in the Lumia Black version of the OS, you can't search for updates directly from the Store application, because this option are not available in the Black update. So, to search for updates you will need to use a third part app, like [SysAppPusher](http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/sysapp-pusher/19d44d9e-f18e-4df1-9bce-36335242ed2e).The app enables you to quickly check (and be notified of) updates for installed and supported system apps, as well as opening up the ability to add apps from the store you wish to track.

Answer (score -2):

http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Pool-of-Knowledge/Nokia-Windows-Phone-8-App-Updates/td-p/1640082              scan the code and you will get it..

Comment: Can you add more detail? If the link goes dead in the future, no one will be able to know what the correct actions are. It is still good to include the link so people themselves can look at the authoritative reference.